# Laravel ["message": "Too few arguments to function App\\Http\\Controllers\\BursaPembelianController::edit_bursa_pembelian(), 1 passed in

Tags: javascript, laravel

hi i want to ask you something, i am having problem in my laravel project where i always find message "message": "Too few arguments to function App\\Http\\Controllers\\BursaPembelianController::edit_bursa_pembelian()....

please give me a solution to the problem I'm facing regarding the error message, below I provide the source code view that I made.

view:

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('container')

    <body class="InvPinjam()">
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="page-title-box d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                            <h4 class="mb-sm-0 font-size-18">{{ $label }}</h4>
                            <div class="page-title-right">
                                <ol class="breadcrumb m-0">
                                    <li class="breadcrumb-item">{{ ucwords($menu) }}</li>
                                    <li class="breadcrumb-item">{{ ucwords($submenu) }}</li>
                                </ol>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-2 peminjam">
                                        <div class="mb-2">
                                            <label>Kode Pembelian <code>*</code></label>
                                            <input type="disable" class="form-control" id="kode_transaksi"
                                                name="kode_transaksi" value="{{ $pembelian->kode_transaksi }}" disabled>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="purchase_id" id="purchase_id"
                                                value="{{ $pembelian->id }}">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url"
                                                value="{{ Crypt::encryptString($pembelian->kode_transaksi) }}">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 peminjam">
                                        <div class="mb-2">
                                            <label>Tanggal <code>*</code></label>
                                            <input type="disable" class="form-control" name="tgl_kedatangan"
                                                id="tgl_kedatangan" value="{{ $pembelian->tgl_kedatangan }}" readonly>
                                            <input type="disable" class="form-control" name="id_peminjam" id="id_peminjam"
                                                value="" hidden>
                                            {!! $errors->first('nama_peminjam', '<div class="invalid-validasi">:message</div>') !!}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 wajib">
                                        <div class="mb-2">
                                            <label>Supplier </label>
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="supplier" id="supplier"
                                                    value="{{ $pembelian->id_supplier }}">
                                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="mdi mdi-calendar"></i></span>

                                            </div>
                                            {!! $errors->first('tgl_permintaan', '<div class="invalid-validasi">:message</div>') !!}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 wajib">
                                        <div class="mb-2">
                                            <label>Surat Jalan </label>
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="suratjalan" id="suratjalan"
                                                    value="{{ $pembelian->nomor_do }}">
                                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="mdi mdi-calendar"></i></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 wajib">
                                        <div class="mb-2">
                                            <label>Status Pembayaran </label>
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pembayaran" id="pembayaran"
                                                    value="{{ $pembelian->status_pembayaran }}">
                                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="mdi mdi-calendar"></i></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 wajib">
                                        <div class="mb-2">
                                            <label>Potongan </label>
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="potongan" id="potongan"
                                                    value="{{ $pembelian->potongan }}">
                                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="mdi mdi-calendar"></i></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                {{-- keterengan --}}
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-2 peminjam">
                                        <div class="mb-2">
                                            <label>Ongkir <code>*</code></label>
                                            <input type="disable" class="form-control" id="kode_transaksi"
                                                name="kode_transaksi" value="{{ $pembelian->ongkir ?? 0 }}">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 peminjam">
                                        <div class="mb-2">
                                            <label>Keterangan <code>*</code></label>
                                            <textarea id="keterangan" class="form-control" name="keterangan" style="height: 50px;" placeholder="Keterangan"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>



                            </div>
                            {{-- //keterangan --}}
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-striped" id="tableList">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th class="text-center" style="width: 5%">No</th>
                                                <th class="text-center" style="width: 20%">Produk
                                                </th>
                                                <th class="text-center" style="width: 15%">kadaluarsa</th>
                                                <th class="text-center" style="width: 15%">Harga</th>
                                                <th class="text-center" style="width: 15%">Kuantiti</th>
                                                <th class="text-center" style="width: 15%">Harga Satuan</th>
                                                <th class="text-center" style="width: 15%">Harga Jual</th>
                                                <th class="text-center" style="width: 15%">Aksi</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        @foreach ($produk as $item)
                                            <tbody>
                                                <td class="text-center" style="width: 5%">
                                                    {{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                                                <td class="text-center" style="width: 20%">
                                                    {{ $item->produk->nama }}</td>
                                                <td class="text-center" style="width: 15%">
                                                    {{ $item->kadaluarsa }}</td>
                                                <td class="text-center" style="width: 15%">
                                                    {{ $item->harga_total_produk }}</td>
                                                <td class="text-center" style="width: 15%">
                                                    {{ $item->total_kuantiti }}</td>
                                                <td class="text-center" style="width: 15%">
                                                    {{ $item->nilai_per_pcs }}</td>
                                                <td class="text-center" style="width: 15%">
                                                    {{ $item->nilai_jual }}</td>
                                                <td class="text-center">

                                                    <?php $id = Crypt::encryptString($item->id); ?>
                                                    <form class="delete-form"
                                                        action="{{ route('inv_pinjaman.destroy_invid', $id) }}"
                                                        method="POST">
                                                        @csrf
                                                        @method('DELETE')

                                                        <div class="d-flex gap-3">
                                                            <a href class="text-danger delete_confirm"><i
                                                                    class="mdi mdi-delete font-size-18"></i></a>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </form>
                                                </td>

                                            </tbody>
                                        @endforeach

                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mt-4">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="tambahBaris">Tambah
                                        Baris</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="row mt-4">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <a href="{{ route('bursa_pembelian.index') }}"
                                        class="btn btn-secondary waves-effect">Kembali</a>
                                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="simpanDataBtn">Simpan</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/alert.js') }}"></script>

    <script>
        //form tambah baris
        document.getElementById("tambahBaris").addEventListener("click", function() {
            var table = document.getElementById("tableList");
            var row = table.insertRow();
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            cell1.innerHTML = rowCount;

            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var pilihProduk = document.createElement("select");
            pilihProduk.className = "form-control select select2 produk";
            pilihProduk.name = "produk";
            pilihProduk.id = "produk";
            pilihProduk.required = true;

            var defaultOption = document.createElement("option");
            defaultOption.value = "";
            defaultOption.text = "--PILIH PRODUK--";
            defaultOption.required = true;
            pilihProduk.appendChild(defaultOption);

            @foreach ($barang as $barangs)
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.value = "{{ $barangs->id }}";
                option.dataset.id = "{{ $barangs->nama }}";
                option.text = "{{ $barangs->nama }}";
                pilihProduk.appendChild(option);
            @endforeach

            cell2.appendChild(pilihProduk);

            $(pilihProduk).select2({
                tags: true,
                allowClear: true
            });


            //tangal kadaluarsa
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var kadaluarsa = document.createElement("input");
            kadaluarsa.type = "text";
            kadaluarsa.className = "form-control";
            kadaluarsa.name = "kadaluarsa";
            kadaluarsa.id = "kadaluarsa";
            kadaluarsa.placeholder = "Kadaluarsa";
            kadaluarsa.required = true;

            cell3.appendChild(kadaluarsa);

            // Inisialisasi Datepicker
            $(kadaluarsa).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            });

            //Harga
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            cell4.innerHTML =
                '<input type="number" class="form-control" name="harga" id="harga" placeholder="Total Harga" required>';

            //kuantitas
            var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
            cell5.innerHTML =
                '<input type="number" class="form-control" min="1" name="kuantitas" id="kuantitas" placeholder="Jumlah" oninput="updateHargaSatuan(this)" required>';

            //harga satuan
            var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
            cell6.innerHTML =
                '<input type="number" class="form-control" name="harsat" id="harsat" placeholder="harsat" readonly>';


            //harga jual
            var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
            cell7.innerHTML =
                '<input type="number" class="form-control" name="harjual[]" id="harjual" placeholder="Harga Jual" required>';

            //button hapus
            var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
            cell8.innerHTML =
                '<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="hapusBaris(this)">Hapus</button>';
        });

        function hapusBaris(button) {
            var row = button.parentNode.parentNode;
            row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
        }

        //fungsi untuk mengisi harga satuan
        function updateHargaSatuan(input) {
            var row = input.parentNode.parentNode;
            var hargaInput = row.querySelector('[name="harga"]');
            var hargaSatuanInput = row.querySelector('[name="harsat"]');

            var harga = parseFloat(hargaInput.value);
            var kuantitas = parseFloat(input.value);

            if (!isNaN(harga) && !isNaN(kuantitas) && kuantitas !== 0) {
                var hargaSatuan = harga / kuantitas;
                hargaSatuanInput.value = hargaSatuan.toFixed(2);
            }
        }


        $('#simpanDataBtn').click(function() {
            var dataedit = [];

            $('#tableList tbody tr').each(function() {
                var purchase_id = document.getElementById('purchase_id').value;
                var kode_transaksi = document.getElementById('kode_transaksi').value;
                var supplier = document.getElementById('supplier').value;
                var suratjalan = document.getElementById('suratjalan').value;
                var pembayaran = document.getElementById('pembayaran').value;
                var potongan = document.getElementById('potongan').value;
                var keterangan = document.getElementById('keterangan').value;

                var produk = $(this).find('[name="produk"]').val();
                var kadaluarsa = $(this).find('[name="kadaluarsa"]').val();
                var harga = $(this).find('[name="harga"]').val();
                var kuantitas = $(this).find('[name="kuantitas"]').val();
                var hargaSatuan = $(this).find('[name="harsat"]').val();
                var hargaJual = $(this).find('[name="harjual"]').val();


                var rowData = {
                    purchase_id: purchase_id,
                    kode_transaksi: kode_transaksi,
                    supplier: supplier,
                    suratjalan: suratjalan,
                    pembayaran: pembayaran,
                    potongan: potongan,
                    keterangan: keterangan,
                    produk: produk,
                    kadaluarsa: kadaluarsa,
                    harga: harga,
                    kuantitas: kuantitas,
                    hargaSatuan: hargaSatuan,
                    hargaJual: hargaJual
                };

                dataedit.push(rowData);
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{{ route('bursa_pembelian.edit_jumlah_pembelian') }}',
                data: {
                    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        data: dataedit
                    })
                },
                success: (response) => {
                    console.log(response)
                    if (response.code === 200) {
                        Swal.fire(
                            'Success',
                            `${response.message}`,
                            'success'
                        ).then(() => {
                            var APP_URL = {!! json_encode(url('/')) !!}
                            console.log(APP_URL)
                            url = document.getElementById("url").value;
                            window.location = APP_URL + '/bursa/bursa_pembelian/' +
                                url +
                                '/edit'
                        })
                    } else {
                        Swal.fire(
                            'Gagal',
                            `${response.message}`,
                            'error',
                        )
                    }
                },
                error: err => console.log(err)
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

web/routing:

```
Route::post('/edit_bursa_pembelian/{id}', [BursaPembelianController::class, 'edit_bursa_pembelian'])->name('bursa_pembelian.edit_jumlah_pembelian');
```

controller:

```
    public function edit_bursa_pembelian(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $updatepembelian = new BursaDetilPembelian();
        $updatepembelian->id_pembelian = $request->data['purchase_id'];
        $updatepembelian->id_produk = $request->data['produk'];
        $updatepembelian->harga_total_produk = $request->data['harga'];
        $updatepembelian->total_kuantiti  = $request->data['kuantitas'];
        $updatepembelian->nilai_per_pcs = $request->data['hargaSatuan'];
        $updatepembelian->nilai_jual = $request->data['hargaJual'];
        $updatepembelian->user_updated =  Auth::user()->id;
        $updatepembelian->save();
    }
```

Detail Error

```
    "message": "Too few arguments to function App\\Http\\Controllers\\BursaPembelianController::edit_bursa_pembelian(), 1 passed in D:\\Leo\\dw\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 2 expected",
    "exception": "ArgumentCountError",
    "file": "D:\\Leo\\dw\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\BursaPembelianController.php",
    "line": 311,
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Please reduce it to a [**minimal**, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also please post the **complete** error message you get, maybe highlight the line where the error occurs.

Comment: fyi, `<input type="disable"` - there is no `type="disable"`

Comment: fyi, `<td>` is not allowed inside `<tbody>`

Comment: Hi I've posted the error message in full

Comment: Error says it's in `BursaPembelianController.php` line 311. Can you show us code that is in this line?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for error is this expression:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '{{ route('bursa_pembelian.edit_jumlah_pembelian') }}',
```

When you are using `route` function with route that has some parameters, you have to pass them.

For example (source from the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes)):

```php
Route::get('/user/{id}/profile', function (string $id) {
    // ...
})->name('profile');
 
$url = route('profile', ['id' => 1]);
```

So for your particular use case, you'd have to specify id of edited resource (`$id` is placeholder):

```php
{{ route('bursa_pembelian.edit_jumlah_pembelian', ['id' => $id]) }}
```